# Regarding catalog_xmin in Replication slot

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication, pg-logical, pg-catalog

Definition of catalog_xmin from postgres Documentation:-

**The oldest transaction affecting the system catalogs that this slot needs the database to retain. VACUUM cannot remove catalog tuples deleted by any later transaction.**

I have established logical replication between publisher and subscriber where publisher sends some data from the table called **data(int,varchar)** to subscriber.First I tried to insert some data as shown in figure below.

[image]

My Question:-
Why does the catalog_xmin value changed from 584 to 585..?As per definition of catalog_xmin,it is something related to system catalog tables,I hope that above mentioned transaction does not effect the system catalog tables...but still why the value is changed?